# How to filter an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

This is an array:

```
total = ["10%", 1000, "5%", 2000]
```

How can I filter these into two arrays like:

```
percentage = ["10%","5%"]
absolute = [1000,2000]
```

...using JavaScript array filter.

Comment: Are the values will be in this order only ["percentage', 'absolute', ...] ?

Comment: You really did not search? SO has many Q&A on such filters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `filter` method, which accepts a `callback` function.

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

Also, use `typeof` **operator** in order to find out the type of item from array. The **typeof** operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

```js
let total = ["10%", "1000", "5%", "2000"];
let percentage = total.filter(function(item){
  return typeof item == 'string' && item.includes('%');
});
console.log(percentage);
let absolute = total.filter(function(item){
  return typeof item == 'number' || !isNaN(item);
});
console.log(absolute);
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
let total = ["10%", 1000, "5%", 2000];

let percents = total.filter(item => item.toString().includes('%'));
let numbers = total.filter(item => !item.toString().includes('%'));
console.log(percents, numbers);
```

Comment: You got the negation for filter condition in reverse.

Comment: @vkgade what do you mean?

Comment: The percents is the one which has '%' character , you negated the return value in percents instead of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
Make two arrays from one array by separating number and string using advance  
js.
```

```js
let total = ["10%", 1000, "5%", 2000];
var percentage = total.filter(e => isNaN(e));
var absolute = total.filter(e => !isNaN(e));
console.log({percentage , absolute});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions since you have only strings in your array.

For % :

```
total.filter(function(element){
    return /^[0-9]+\%$/gi.test(element);
});
```

For absolute :

```
total.filter(function(element){
    return /^[0-9]+$/gi.test(element);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array#reduce to split the array:

```js
const total = ["10%", 1000, "5%", 2000];

const { absolute, percentage } = total.reduce((arrs, item) => {
  const key = typeof item === 'number' ? 'absolute' : 'percentage';
  
  arrs[key].push(item);
  
  return arrs;
}, { percentage: [], absolute: [] });

console.log(absolute);

console.log(percentage);
```

Answer (score 1):

For brevity with using ES2015 , if you plan to simply clear the array (this is an example, insert your own function for element "e", of course):

```js
let MyArray = [1,2,3,4,5]

MyArray = [].concat(MyArray.filter(e => e > 2))

console.log(MyArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using

```js
let total = ["10%", 1000, "5%", 2000]


let result1 = total.filter(function(element){
    if(typeof element == "number"){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
})
let result2 = total.filter(function(element){
    if(typeof element == "string" && element.match(/\%$/)){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
})
console.log(result1, result2);
```

> the first array filter all the number 
>   the 2nd array filter elements which are a string and have a "%" in the end

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$array = array('10%', '1000', '20%','2000');
```

//for show integer from array

print_r(array_filter($array, function ($var) { return (stripos($var, '%') === false); }));

//for show % array

print_r(array_filter($array, function ($var) { return (stripos($var, '%') == true); }));

Answer (score 0):

```
let total = ["10%", "1000", "5%", "2000"];
let percentage = total.filter(function(item){
  return typeof item == 'string' && item.includes('%');
});
console.log(percentage);
let absolute = total.filter(function(item){
  return typeof item == 'number' || !isNaN(item);
});
console.log(absolute);
```