# How do I filter certain items in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array

```
let arr = [ 'file_1.jpg' , 'file_2.png', 'file_3.pdf', 'file_4.html', 'folder.db' ]
```

I want to filter the files that has .jpg and .png on it.

```
arr.filter() // desired output: [ 'file_1.png','file_2.png' ]
```

Comment: Google "how to filter an array in JavaScript": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter You even used the correct function name in your example...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter an array in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916135/how-to-filter-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: So many answers, so little VTC as duplicate

Comment: What's with all then downvotes? Why so much noob bashing on this site?

Comment: @darksky Because it shows _absolutely zero research effort,_ please see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Questions do not get down-voted for being from noobs, _everyone starts somewhere._ They get down-voted and closed because they are not suitable for SO. There is a minimum effort expected before posting. Also, having 10 exact duplicate questions pollutes the site with noise: the whole idea is to have a single authoritative answer for a given case.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr.filter(link => link.endsWith(".png") || link.endsWith(".jpg"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Filter with a RegExp:

```js
const arr = [ 'file_1.jpg' , 'file_2.png', 'file_3.pdf', 'file_4.html', 'folder.db' ];

const pattern = /\.(png|jpg)$/; // string should end with .png or .jpg
const result = arr.filter((name) => pattern.test(name));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 const result = arr.filter( link => link.endsWith(".png") || link.endsWith(".jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Filter Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

The filter function accepts one callback function which returns a boolean for each item of the list.

So you could create a `function` that is using a `regular expression` to check if a `string` is a `png` or `jpg`.

### Creating the filtering expression

- In JavaScript regular expressions look like this: `//`
- The dot is a special character (match any character) so you need to escape it: `/\./`
- To match a string from a collection of strings you can use `()` and separate the options using a pipe `(|)`: `/\.(jpg|png)/`
- You can check if that is the end of text by adding `$` at the end: `/\.(jpg|png)$/`

Then using the [test function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) you can check if a string matches your expression.

```
arr.filter(isJPEG);

function isJPEG(text) {
    return /\.(jpg|png)$/.test(text);
}
```

### Working Example

```js
var arr = ['file_1.jpg', 'file_2.png', 'file_3.pdf', 'file_4.html', 'folder.db'];

var filteredList = arr.filter(isJPEG);

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredList));

function isJPEG(text) {
    return /\.(jpg|png)$/.test(text);
}
```