# Filter JSON data (containing object array) in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

**
Below is my JSON data

> I want to filter and have data that is having rulescore > 0  using  nodejs

**

```
{
 "https://www.google.com":{
   "sitescore":99,
       "rules":[
            {
        "rulename":"rule1","rulescore":0,"description":"rules1 descript"},
            {
        "rulename":"rule2","rulescore":1,"description":"rules2 descript"},
            {
        "rulename":"rule3","rulescore":0,"description":"rules3 descript"}
            ]
           }
}
```

**

> I want to filter and have data that is having rulescore > 0  using  nodejs

**

Comment: What `filter`s have you tried so far? Post your code if you want help debugging

Comment: start by converting JSON to javascript objects, you'll thank me later

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter an array in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916135/how-to-filter-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: I tried using npm packages  underscore but i am not getting how to do

Comment: @VedaVyas why would you bother with underscore when Arrays have a `filter` method? See [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter` operation on the `rules` array to get the rules with `rulescore` that are greater than 0.

```js
var dataObj = {
 "sitename":{
   "sitescore":99,
   "rules":[
     {
       "rulename":"rule1","rulescore":0,"description":"rules1 descript"
     },
     {
       "rulename":"rule2","rulescore":1,"description":"rules2 descript"
     },
     {
       "rulename":"rule3","rulescore":0,"description":"rules3 descript"
     }
   ]
 }
};

var res = dataObj.sitename.rules.filter((rule) => rule.rulescore > 0);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

## ES6

You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of array.

**DEMO**

```js
const data = {
    "sitename": {
        "sitescore": 99,
        "rules": [{
            "rulename": "rule1",
            "rulescore": 0,
            "description": "rules1 descript"
        }, {
            "rulename": "rule2",
            "rulescore": 1,
            "description": "rules2 descript"
        }, {
            "rulename": "rule3",
            "rulescore": 0,
            "description": "rules3 descript"
        }]
    }
};


console.log(data.sitename.rules.filter(({rulescore}) => rulescore > 0));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var dataObj={
         "https://www.google.com":{
        "sitescore":99,
         "rules":[
                {
             "rulename":"rule1","rulescore":0,"description":"rules1 descript"},
              {
             "rulename":"rule2","rulescore":1,"description":"rules2 descript"},
               {
             "rulename":"rule3","rulescore":0,"description":"rules3 descript"}
             ]
             }
       };

      var res = (dataObj["https://www.google.com"]).rules.filter(rule => 
   rule.rulescore > 0);
       console.log(res);
```