# Adding a filter to Vue.js table using computed properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table generated using an array of objects.  I am having a hard time figuring out how to use computed properties to filter the array of objects.  I am using VuE.js.  I'm not sure how to properly use the filter() in my computed properties to filter the table.

```
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: () => ({
    search:'',
    programs: [],
    editableKeys: ['date', 'company', 'funding', 'funded', 'recruit', 'program'],
  }),
  created () {
    this.getPrograms();
  },
  methods: {
    getPrograms() {
     axios.get("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/isogunro/jsondb/Programs").then(response => {
       this.programs = response.data.map(program => ({
           ...program,
           isReadOnly: true,
            dropDowns: ["Apple","Google"]
       }));
      }).catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
      });
    },
    editItem (program) {
      program.isReadOnly = false
    },
    saveItem (program) {
      program.isReadOnly = true
      console.log(program)
      alert("New Value: "+program.company)
      alert("Previous Value: "+program.company)
    },
    bgColor (program) {
      return program.funded === program.funding ? 'yellow' : 'white'
    },
    formatDate(program){
      var formatL = moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L');
      var format2digitYear = formatL.replace(/YYYY/g,'YY');
      return moment(program.Date).format(format2digitYear);
    },
    updateField(program){
      console.log(program)
      alert(program)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    searchContents(){
      this.programs.filter(this.search === )//??? not sure how to filter correctly
    }
  }
})
```

Here's the [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/bGGrWZG?editors=1011)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter an array in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916135/how-to-filter-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Computed properties have to return a value, and you can use it as same as data and props. So what you need to do is return the result of the filter. For the case with no `search` option, you can return raw `programs` without the filter.

The computed property will be like this:
(if you filter the programs by it's `funding` attribute.)

```js
computed: {
  searchContents(){
    if (this.search === '') {
      return this.programs
    }

    return this.programs.filter(x => this.search === x.funding)
  }
}
```

Then you can use that computed property in `v-for`:

```
  <tr v-for="(program, index) in searchContents">
```

Comment: I made the change but nothing happens.  https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/bGGrWZG?editors=1011

Comment: It looks working. When you type `NO` on the search box, the table shows only the data which has `NO` as the value of `funding`.

Comment: Oh...I was expecting a gradual search..so if I type ```N```, I would see anything starting with ```N```