# restrict a bookmarklet that opens a random link on page

Tags: javascript, random, bookmarklet

I found this bookmarklet that opens a random link on your current page.

```
javascript:void(window.open(document.links[Math.floor(Math.random()*document.links.length)].href,'_self'));
```

I wanted to use this on a website, but I also wanted to restrict it so certain links wouldn't be opened. Is there a way I can do this?

(also I found the bookmarklet [here](https://ask.metafilter.com/179507/bookmarklet-for-a-random-link-in-a-new-tab))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main point that you are looking for is how to [filter an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916135/how-to-filter-an-array-in-javascript).

You might notice that `document.links.filter()` throws an error, that's because [it's not an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects) per se, but an `HTMLCollection` (it has no `.filter()` methods), so you have to [convert it to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array) first.

I used the most modern way, your usage might differ:

```
[...document.links]
  .filter(link => !link.href.includes('stackoverflow'))
```

Comment: I'm a little confused how I would implement this into what I have... I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: This will return a filtered array, which you can access the same way as your current code `[Math.floor(Math.random()*document.links.length)]`. Can you edit your question with the updated approach?