# json server array filter by query parameter

Tags: angular, api, express, httpserver, json-server

Hi guys I have following json structure on json server I would like to filter the data
by passing a query parameter dealType=PC

```
[
    {
        "deals": [
            {
                "dealName": "KF001",
                "dealType": "PC",
                "statusType": "Designated",
                "scenarios": [
                    {
                        "scenarioName": "Undesignated",
                        "scenarioOfficialIndicator": "N",
                        "loans": [
                            {
                                "freLoanId": 1,
                                "loanAmt": 43,
                                "interestRate": 11.58
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "dealName": "KF001",
                "dealType": "SB",
                "statusType": "InMaket",
                "scenarios": [
                    {
                        "scenarioName": "Undesignated",
                        "scenarioOfficialIndicator": "Y",
                        "loans": [
                            {
                                "freLoanId": 1,
                                "loanAmt": 16,
                                "interestRate": 7.06
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "dealName": "KF002",
                "dealType": "UND",
                "statusType": "Designated",
                "scenarios": [
                    {
                        "scenarioName": "SrPoolB",
                        "scenarioOfficialIndicator": "N",
                        "loans": [
                            {
                                "freLoanId": 1,
                                "loanAmt": 1,
                                "interestRate": 1.93
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

https://my.api.mockaroo.com/loan-pipeline.json?key=bd565ab0

I would like to filter the data by passing a query parameter dealType=PC

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` method on array https://stackoverflow.com/a/45916177/13889280

example:

```js
data = [{...}];
d = data[0]; // I assume only one data
pcDeals = d.deals.filter((x) => {return x.dealType == "PC"});
```

Comment: Hi Yusuf where do I add the method for json-server ?